# CAS SSO "mvn package" Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war

Tags: maven, cas

i got this error after doing "mvn package" , i am working on CAS and Acitve Directory

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war (default-war) on project cas-server-webapp: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:war failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:jar:2.1.1 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.4.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:pom:2.4.1 from/to mojo-snapshot (https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/codehaus-snapshots/): nexus.codehaus.org: Nom ou service inconnu: Unknown host nexus.codehaus.org: Nom ou service inconnu -> [Help 1]

Comment: i use CAS 3.5.2 on debian

Answer (score 0):

you can confirm the package methom whether is 'war'
and you can add this codes at pom.xml

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
         <configuration>
            <webXml>web\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory> -->
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

webXml and warSourceDirectory user your own route